# Splash screen in Android glitch

Tags: java, android, adt, splash-screen

I have developed a splash screen in Android which comes for 2 seconds and go to the main activity. The problem is that when I start the application the main activity comes for few milliseconds and then goes to the splash screen activity. Can I know the solution for this?

**splashscreen.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class splashscreen extends Activity {

    private static int splashInterval = 2000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        etWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);       
       setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);
       new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(splashscreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                this.finish();
            }

            private void finish() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        }, 
        splashInterval);
    };
}
```

**splashscreen.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/splash" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/progressBar1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_marginBottom="58dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Android Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="asdf.splashtest1" >
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <!-- Splash screen -->
        <activity android:name=".splashscreen" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:noHistory="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Main activity -->
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" ></activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

//MainActivity.java
    package asdf.splashtest1;

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }


}
```

Comment: fillparent is deprecated..better add match parent

Comment: Please show the code of your second activity...

Comment: @DaniEll i have added ur request.

Comment: Your code looks ok. I guess there is something wrong with your second activity. Maybe it's terminating itself... Try to lauch it directly (instead of splash screen)

Comment: Does this happen after you force stop your app?

Answer (score 0):

This is my Splash Code Maybe This will helps,

```
Thread Background = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            sleep(2000);
            Intent intent = new Intent(splashscreen.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    };
    Background.start();
}
```

At sleep(2000), enter your desired time in milliseconds.

Edit

```
 private class SplashTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        finish();

        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,
                MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

Call This Async with in onCreate Method `new SplashTask().execute();`

Comment: problem still exists.

Comment: I did it. If u can send me your splash screen code I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @UsamaRehan I edit my code with new async task copy that code and modify classes with yours